# Set default C++ standard in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-tasks, linux

I frequently create small toy programs in vscode. Every time I do, I need to modify the `tasks.json` file to compile using C++20. I would like to use C++20 by default.

**An example solution:** when I open a directory in vscode for the first time, the `tasks.json` file should automatically include the following

```
"args": [
    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
    "-g",
    "-std=c++20",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
],
```

I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried the settings? I believe that they affect compilation and not just Intellisense.

Comment: @sweenish if you mean the "C/C++ Extension" settings "Cpp Standard" and "C standard", then yes, I have changed those settings. I'm not sure what effect those settings have, but they did not cause the compiler to use ```-std=c++20```. I still have to do that myself by modifying ```tasks.json```.

Comment: I believe those settings are just for intellisense. I don't think what you are looking for with tasks.json exists.